GeoServer, SLD version is changed during download
I have a SLD (version 1.1.0) on GeoServer (version 2.24.2)
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <NamedLayer>
    <se:Name>LL Message</se:Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <se:Name>LL Message</se:Name>
      <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
....

When I dowload it through the REST I've got 1.0.0 version of SLD
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><sld:StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" version="1.0.0">
  <sld:NamedLayer>
    <sld:Name>LL Message</sld:Name>
    <sld:UserStyle>
      <sld:Name>LL Message</sld:Name>
      <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <sld:Name>name</sld:Name>
.....

Why is SLD 1.1.0 converted to SLD 1.0.0. during download and how to avoid that? I would like to use SLD 1.1.0 as template, therefore I need it as it is originally stored.

You need to specify the content-type of your file to be SLD 1.1 (application/vnd.ogc.se+xml) when you upload it, as described in the REST API Documents:

Use POST with a style file (application/vnd.ogc.sld+xml or
application/vnd.ogc.se+xml for SLD; additional style types are added
by extensions) to generate a style info and upload the style all at
once. Then separately PUT the style info at /styles/{style} to make
any desired changes to the generated catalog entry. You can also use
POST with a ZIP file to upload a SLD 1.0 (application/vnd.ogc.sld+xml)
file and any associated icon files, and then separately PUT the style
info at /styles/{style}. POST with a ZIP file does not support any
other style types.


Do you answer the right question? OP writes "When I dowload it through the REST I've got 1.0.0 version of SLD"

but the problem is that it got downgraded when they uploaded it, I think, they may also need to specify the correct mime type for the download

Ian, I have made the template from scratch inside GeoServer GUI. Therefore there is a 1.1.0 version of SLD, but I didn't know that even through GET (REST) I have to define mime type. BTW, download through browser is also downgrading version od SLD to 1.0.0.
